# Screen Capture with OpenCV and Python-2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, video-capture

I'm using *Python 2.7* and *OpenCV 2.4.9*.

I need to capture the current frame that is being shown to the user and load it as an *cv::**Mat*** object in Python.

Do you guys know a fast way to do it recursively?

I need something like what's done in the example below, that captures ***Mat*** frames from a webcam recursively:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('WindowName', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

In the example it's used the *VideoCapture class* to work with the captured image from the webcam.

With VideoCapture.read() a new frame is always being readed and stored into a ***Mat*** object.

Could I load a *"printscreens stream"* into a VideoCapture object? Could I create a streaming of my computer's screen with OpenCV in Python, without having to save and delete lots of *.bmp* files per second?

I need this frames to be ***Mat*** objects or ***NumPy arrays***, so I can perform some Computer Vision routines with this frames in real time.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your question actually is. Could you edit your question to clarify exactly what it is? For example, what do you mean 'recursively'? `frame` already contains the image. Why don't you just use it directly?

Comment: @Aurelius From What I understand, he's just looking for a way to inject printscreens as frames instead of images from the webcam. Since the monitor is not included in the device list taken by `cv2.VideoCapture`, You just need to grab the printscreen from elsewhere, such as **PIL `Image.Imagegrab.grab()`**, convert it to a numpy array, and inject it in the code shown above as a frame...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That's a solution code I've written using @Raoul tips.

I used PIL ImageGrab module to grab the printscreen frames.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2

while(True):
    printscreen_pil =  ImageGrab.grab()
    printscreen_numpy =   np.array(printscreen_pil.getdata(),dtype='uint8')\
    .reshape((printscreen_pil.size[1],printscreen_pil.size[0],3)) 
    cv2.imshow('window',printscreen_numpy)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: When using this solution I was getting the error that uint8 is undefined.  Wrapping it in single quotes as 'uint8' all began to work.

Comment: Why did you do .reshape() and how does it work? The documentation is a bit difficult to understand. I get "ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged"

Comment: @jsleuth Sorry, my mistake, you can use dtype = numpy.uint8

Comment: @andii Reshape is a method of objects numpy.ndarray. I've reshaped the array because an image is a matrix (n,m), with n rows and m columns. I am transforming a flattened array into a matrix (n,m) with the method reshape.

Comment: I get a speed (framerate) increase of almost 100x if I change `np.array(printscreen_pil.getdata(), dtype=uint8)` to `np.array(printscreen_pil, dtype=uint8)`.

Comment: Attention: `ImportError: ImageGrab is macOS and Windows only`

Comment: It seems like my mac (OSX 10.11) does not support cv2.imshow('window',printscreen_numpy) I am using Python 3.5.0 and Opencv 3.1.0

Comment: >>> cv2.imshow('window', ps_numpy)
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Abort trap: 6

Comment: Using this method inverts colors, (pillow uses RGB but OpenCV uses BGR) you might want to add this line: ```im_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(printscreen_numpy, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    cv2.imshow('window',im_bgr)```

Answer (score 24):

I had frame rate problems with other solutions, [mss](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/) solve them.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image

mon = {'top': 160, 'left': 160, 'width': 200, 'height': 200}

sct = mss()

while 1:
    sct.get_pixels(mon)
    img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (sct.width, sct.height), sct.image)
    cv2.imshow('test', np.array(img))
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: my frame rate went from 0.8s using PIL `ImageGrab` to 0.06s using `mss`, thank you sir!

Comment: Default `pip install mss` will install latest version where MSS has no attribute `get_pixels`. Need to `pip install mss==2.0.22` for `sct.get_pixels()` to work.

Comment: Look at my answer for the latest version of `mss`

Answer (score 4):

This is the updated answer for the answer by @Neabfi

```py
import time

import cv2
import numpy as np
from mss import mss

mon = {'top': 160, 'left': 160, 'width': 200, 'height': 200}
with mss() as sct:
    # mon = sct.monitors[0]
    while True:
        last_time = time.time()
        img = sct.grab(mon)
        print('fps: {0}'.format(1 / (time.time()-last_time)))
        cv2.imw('test', np.array(img))
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

And to save to a mp4 video

```py
import time

import cv2
import numpy as np
from mss import mss


def record(name):
    with mss() as sct:
        # mon = {'top': 160, 'left': 160, 'width': 200, 'height': 200}
        mon = sct.monitors[0]
        name = name + '.mp4'
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
        desired_fps = 30.0
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(name, fourcc, desired_fps,
                              (mon['width'], mon['height']))
        last_time = 0
        while True:
            img = sct.grab(mon)
            # cv2.imshow('test', np.array(img))
            if time.time() - last_time > 1./desired_fps:
                last_time = time.time()
                destRGB = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
                out.write(destRGB)
            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break


record("Video")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Python 3 Implementation

This Function finds the Application in the List of Running Applications:

```
def capture_dynamic():
    toplist, winlist = [], []
    
    def enum_cb(hwnd, results):
        winlist.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))
        
    win32gui.EnumWindows(enum_cb, toplist)

    wnd = [(hwnd, title) for hwnd, title in winlist if 'spotify' in title.lower()]

    if wnd:
        wnd = wnd[0]
        hwnd = wnd[0]

        bbox = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox)
        return img
    else:
        return None
```

This Function Displays the Images until the Letter 'q' is pressed:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

while(True):
#   Dynamic Version
    screen_grab =  capture_dynamic()
    
    if(screen_grab == None):
        print("No Window Found! Please Try Again")
        break
        
    screen_grab = np.array(screen_grab)
    cv2.imshow('window',cv2.cvtColor(screen_grab, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Make sure the Application you want to capture should be in the Foreground and not behind any other Application

**Please Upvote!**