# Capturing screen/window content with Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, screen-capture

Currently learning opencv in Python. I want to do some image/pixel analysis with the screen.

With opencv/python, I wonder if there is a way to capture the visual content of a window of another software.

For example if I start a game in a window, I want opencv or python to capture the pixel content of that game window and run analysis for that content.

In the same fashion, if I play a fullscreen video with a video player, I would also like to capture the pixel content of the fullscreen and run  analysis for that content with opencv/python.

I am not sure if opencv is the best way to do this. If you have suggestions for more suitable libraries, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "pixel content"? Do you want to detect a specific shape? Do you want to detect the border of your application?

Comment: Yes, that kind of operations. Like detecting edges, gradients of shades, etc... Why? Do you have a better suggestions?

Comment: This is rather general. Yes, you can use OpenCV to detect edges/gradients/shades. If the question is if OpenCV can solve this the answer is yes. I was wondering if you have a specific problem.

Comment: But my question is how to capture the display of the window of another application. I know OpenCV can do those and that's why I am using OpenCV.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. You can grab the display of a video or application and process the contents using OpenCV. I have linked you a solution to both applications below. See if that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For your second use case (capture a video frame) you could use the [OpenCV Video Capture Feature](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html). You can essentially open an .avi file and do operation on different frames.

If you want to grab the contents of a specific application you could do so in a similar fashion as already described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35098049/6436977). All you need to know is the specific position of your application window where you want to extract your information from.