# How to get the coordinates of the cv2.imshow window?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, screen-capture

I am using this code

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab as ig
import time

last_time = time.time()
while(True):
    screen = ig.grab(bbox=(200, 200, 600, 600))
    print('Loop took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-last_time))
    cv2.imshow("test", np.array(screen))
    last_time = time.time()
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097837/capture-video-data-from-screen-in-python) question on SO.
This is my output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4jBT.jpg)

This works fine. I am looking for a solution where I can capture the area just under the output window. When I move the window around, the output changes as well. One way would be to update this line as follows:

```py
screen = ig.grab(bbox=(x1, y2, x2, y2))
```

but thing I can't figure out is that how to get these parameters values. Or how to get the coordinates of the output window?

P.S. I don't have enough reputation to embed images here directly so I added the external link.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 x64.

Comment: This might get you started... https://gist.github.com/proxb/d9d9f2090b7bf6bccbac

Comment: @SarmadGulzar: Do the opposide, sync it by place the `cv2` window using `cv2.resizeWindow(self.winname, width, height) ; cv2.moveWindow(self.winname, x, y)`

Comment: I got it using [cv2.getWindowImageRect()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga73b55e9851b5691f6a6a4a4e6c57258e)