# How would I be able to capture a live video feed of my laptops screen?

Tags: python

I'm not sure how to describe what I am trying to do but ill give it a shot. I have used TensorFlow and OpenCV to open my laptop's camera to detect images from this [link](https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/object-detection-using-tensorflow/). Simple stuff.

Now I want to open my laptop's screen to detect images. For example, I want to be able to play games and perform tasks like clicking buttons and such. I know that pyautogui exists but it's too slow for my use.

In conclusion, is there any module out there that can reliably get live stable footage of my laptop's screen and me able to implement actions like clicking? I hope that is enough information.

Edit:
With the help of LBJ I have located the information I need but now I have another question. How would I replace the last bit of code with another bit of code (keep scrolling to see what I mean)

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
import pathlib
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
 
while "models" in pathlib.Path.cwd().parts:
    os.chdir('..')
 
def load_model(model_name):
  base_url = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'
  model_file = model_name + '.tar.gz'
  model_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    fname=model_name, 
    origin=base_url + model_file,
    untar=True)
 
  model_dir = pathlib.Path(model_dir)/"saved_model"
  model = tf.saved_model.load(str(model_dir))
  return model
 
PATH_TO_LABELS = 'models/research/object_detection/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt'
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)
 
model_name = 'ssd_inception_v2_coco_2017_11_17'
detection_model = load_model(model_name)
 
def run_inference_for_single_image(model, image):
  image = np.asarray(image)
  # The input needs to be a tensor, convert it using `tf.convert_to_tensor`.
  input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image)
  # The model expects a batch of images, so add an axis with `tf.newaxis`.
  input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis,...]
 
  # Run inference
  model_fn = model.signatures['serving_default']
  output_dict = model_fn(input_tensor)
 
  # All outputs are batches tensors.
  # Convert to numpy arrays, and take index [0] to remove the batch dimension.
  # We're only interested in the first num_detections.
  num_detections = int(output_dict.pop('num_detections'))
  output_dict = {key:value[0, :num_detections].numpy() 
                 for key,value in output_dict.items()}
  output_dict['num_detections'] = num_detections
 
  # detection_classes should be ints.
  output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)
    
  # Handle models with masks:
  if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
    # Reframe the the bbox mask to the image size.
    detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
              output_dict['detection_masks'], output_dict['detection_boxes'],
               image.shape[0], image.shape[1])      
    detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(detection_masks_reframed > 0.5,
                                       tf.uint8)
    output_dict['detection_masks_reframed'] = detection_masks_reframed.numpy()
     
  return output_dict

def show_inference(model, frame):
  #take the frame from webcam feed and convert that to array
  image_np = np.array(frame)
  # Actual detection.
     
  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(model, image_np)
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks_reframed', None),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=5)
 
  return(image_np)

#Now we open the webcam and start detecting objects
import cv2
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    re,frame = video_capture.read()
    Imagenp=show_inference(detection_model, frame)
    cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(Imagenp, (800,600)))
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Im using this code above from [here](https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/object-detection-using-tensorflow/) and I want to see if I can replace this piece of code below:

```
#Now we open the webcam and start detecting objects
import cv2
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    re,frame = video_capture.read()
    Imagenp=show_inference(detection_model, frame)
    cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(Imagenp, (800,600)))
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code above uses the camera and already came with the code from the link. Now I want to use this code below to identify my screen:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image

bounding_box = {'top': 100, 'left': 0, 'width': 1250, 'height': 700}

sct = mss()

while True:
    sct_img = sct.grab(bounding_box)
    cv2.imshow('screen', np.array(sct_img))

    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

The code above is where I want to identify my images. Rather than opening up my camera I can use my screen to identify objects and what not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several modules that provides a solution, it depends on what you intend to use it for. Some examples:

- PIL
- OpenCV
- pyautogui

Since you already have dabbled in OpenCV
[a similar question has been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097837/capture-video-data-from-screen-in-python).

Comment: OpenCV certainly *does not* provide screen capture. it may be useful with further processing, which OP intends to do, but that's beyond the scope of the question.