# Take an input stream from the desktop in OpenCV

Tags: python, macos, opencv, neural-network, python-3.4

I am using *Python 3.5.1* and *OpenCV 3.0.0*.

I am working on a python program that can play games, so it needs to 'see' what is going on, on the screen. How can this be achieved?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    #work with frames here
```

Is there a int 'a' such that cv2.VideoCapture(a) will take the desktop screen as video input? I tried making it and I followed a rather clumsy approach, I captured screen repeatedly using:

```
import os
os.system('screencapture test.jpg')
```

Then opening test.jpg using cv2.imread. This was a very slow approach, on searching online I found this question [Screen Capture with OpenCV and Python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129253/screen-capture-with-opencv-and-python-2-7) which does the same thing, but more efficiently. But the fact still remains that it is capturing individual screenshots and processing them one by one and not a true video stream. I also found this [How to capture the desktop in OpenCV (ie. turn a bitmap into a Mat)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148758/how-to-capture-the-desktop-in-opencv-ie-turn-a-bitmap-into-a-mat) which I think is close to what I am trying but is in C++, if someone can help me convert this to Python, I will highly appreciate it.

The main thing is that the program will be doing something like [MarI/O](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv6UVOQ0F44), so speed is a concern, any help is appreciated, go easy on me, I am (relatively) new to OpenCV.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find anything?

Comment: i did find this, http://sikulix.com/ it sounds promising, but never really tried it. If you do, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update on this question in case anyone wants a solution.

Taking screenshot can be achieved by using module [`pyautogui`](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html)

```
import pyautogui
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = pyautogui.screenshot()
plt.imshow(image)
```

If you want to read it as a stream,

```
while(True):
    image = pyautogui.screenshot()
    #further processing
    if finished:
        break
```

According to the documentation,

> On a 1920 x 1080 screen, the screenshot() function takes roughly 100 milliseconds

So this solution can be used if your application does not demand high fps rate.

Comment: To further improve FPS, you could create a separate thread just for taking screenshots while having the main thread process the frames. You could place the screenshots into a queue so the main thread simply reads the next frame without having to wait for I/O operations.

Answer (score 1):

Taking screenshots in separate thread sounds good solution.
Also you can use virtual webcam, but it is a heavy solution.
Or you would capture desktop directly by using ffmpeg. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop