# Screenshot an area with openCV via python 3.7.3

Tags: python, opencv, screenshot

The end goal of the project is to take in a capture of the screen and output circles in the screenshots locations(midpoint and radius). So very start of this project is capturing the screen and sending it through a circle finding function.
I started here: [Screen Capture with OpenCV and Python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129253/screen-capture-with-opencv-and-python-2-7)

This works for its functionality and on my machine does the `cv2.imshow` sucessfully displays the screenshots as it should. However, I want it to work with this example: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html

Basically, the code in that example works for `cv2.imshow`, however, I want it to work with `cv2.imread` so it's compatible with the example I want to copy.

I've tried a few basic things to no avail, for reference see below!

Attempt 1: http://prntscr.com/n8tpyh

```py
printscreen_pil = Imagegrab()
printscreen_numpy = np.array(printscreen_pil.getdata(),dtype='uint8')
img = cv2.imread(printscreen_humpy , 0)
```

Errors on `cv2.imread` with message

> TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation

Attempt 2: http://prntscr.com/n8tqtp

```py
from mss import mss
mon = {'top':160 , 'left': 160 , 'width': 200, 'height': 200 }
sct = mss()
sct.get_pixels(mon)
```

Errors on `sc.getpixels` with message `` AttributeError: 'MSS' object has no attribute `get_pixels' ``

Attempt 3: https://prnt.sc/n8tw7w

```py
img_grab = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,500,500))
img = np.array(img_grab)
#img = cv2.imread(img)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

Errors on `cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)` with a very long message which I will summarize into `(-2:Unspecified error)` and `Invalid number of channels in input image: 'VScn::contains(scn)' where 'scn' is 3`  for more info please open the screenshot, if not drop a comment and I'll type that chunk for ya!

Attempt 4: http://prntscr.com/n8u0jc

```py
cords = {'top':40 , 'left': 0 , 'width': 800, 'height': 640 }
with mss() as sct :
img = np.array(sct.grab(cords))
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img , cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

Errors on `cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img , cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)` with message I will again summarize to `` Invalid number of channels in input image: `VScn::contains(scn)' where 'scn' is 4 ``

Thanks Everyone!!!!

Comment: Boom, typed out my screenshots for ya!

Comment: I'm not sure about editing my question. I've modified it a bit, is there any portion specifically that is confusing to you? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your attempt 4, use this to define `cimg`:

```
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
```